# Android facebook shimmerFrameLayout set reapeat delay not working correctly?

Tags: android, shimmer

I use ShimmerFrameLayout in the android project. When i set  app:shimmer_repeat_delay="integer" in XML layout file, that changes shimmer_duration(shimmer sweep slowly!). Is this a bug? Does someone have a solution? Thanks for your help.

library url: http://facebook.github.io/shimmer-android

My code is:

```
<com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:shimmer_duration="1500"
        app:shimmer_repeat_delay="4000">
               
                .........

 </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
```